# How to trigger a specific action if the user has been on the website before?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, local-storage

So basically, I have a code on the website where an embedded soundcloud playlist is played once the user arrives on the website. However, I want to do something that a different playlist is played every time the user visits the website. So basically:

```
If user visits the website for the first time
 then play playlist 1
If user visits the website for the second time
 then play playlist 2
If user visits the website for the third time
 then play playlist 3
Elseif user visiting the website for the fourth time
 then play playlist 1 again
```

and repeat.

( I can unto 3-4 different playlists)

I'm kinda new to programming in JS so I was wondering if there's a way of using cookies or local storage to determine the nth time the user is visiting the website and playing a playlist accordingly.

Please let me know if I can provide some more info or clarification. Again, I'm new to relatively new to programming so I apologize for any vagueness.

Comment: See  here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49013384/how-would-you-count-a-users-accumulated-visits-to-your-site-client-side

Answer (score 0):

Yes, cookies are what you have to use. There is a chance that users clear up their cookies but this is how it works. You store the number of visits in cookies and show/do whatever you need depending on that number.